# model.summar by Keras- Is it possible to create the model just from the summary?

Tags: keras

I have the summary of a Sequential model from Keras, is it possible to create the Code of the layers aout of it? I tried lots of different combinations but especially the Conv2D-Layers are problematic for me. Can anybody help out?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrX42.png)

I tried a lot of different combinations but I did not get the same summary. I do not know where the mistake is, all the calculations I found on the internet do not work here.

Answer (score 0):

If the input image has one channel then the number of filter size for the first conv2d layer is 2x2 or it is a 1x1 convolution with 4 channels, the latter seems more plausible, then a 32 3x3 maxpooling with stride of 2, then conv2d with 32 3x3 kernels with stride of 1, then again a 32 3x3 maxpooling with stride 2 then dense layers of sizes - [7200,128,2]

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
import keras.layers as l
model.add(l.Conv2D(32,(1,1)))
model.add(l.MaxPooling2D(32,(3,3),(2,2)))
model.add(l.Conv2D(32,(3,3)))
model.add(l.MaxPooling2D(32,(3,3),(2,2)))
model.add(l.Dense(7200))
model.add(l.Dense(128))
model.add(l.Dense(2))
```